# Why bash aliases commands are not working?

Tags: bash, kali-linux, alias

I am facing a problem with bash alias in Kali linux. Let me tell from the beginning.

I want to set some command to save time from writing it again and again. So, I used

```
nano /.bash_aliases
```

and set a command line

```
alias up='sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade'
```

then I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and hit <kbd>y</kbd> then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I closed the terminal and open it. When I put `up` and press enter it shows:

```
up: command not found
```

Then I searched for solution and find one telling to do this.

```
gedit .bashrc
```

In the .bashrc file this is written without any '#'

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

Then I get into `bash_aliases` file with this command

```
gedit bash_aliases
```

And write this and save...

```
alias up='sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade'
```

and close the terminal. In new terminal that same error happens. No command found. I have also do these in order to solve this problem:

- reboot my pc
- totally turned off and again turn on my pc
- Try some random solutions like

  ```
   source ~/.bashrc
   bash -i -c my_alias
  ```

But I found the problem again and again. Here is a screen shot if I forgot to add any details. Thanks in advance.
[image: Screen Shot of error]

Comment: Did you really edit `/.bash_aliases` or did you mean `~/.bash_aliases`? What user did you edit the file as? You show a terminal where you are logged in as root. If you want this alias for root, why did you use `sudo`? Did you maybe not want it for root but for your regular user?

Comment: You might want to read https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/4667

Comment: Kali Linux does not use `bash` by default. It uses `zsh`, which has its own set of initialization files.  The file `~/.zshrc` would be the one most relevant to this question.

Comment: let's start by noting that `/.bash_aliases`, `~/.bash_aliases`, and `bash_aliases` (in any directory) are three different files. It's seldom useful to try a similar but different filename, or the same filename from a different directory. And based on the above comment, you might want to double-check which shell you're running. try `echo "bash=$BASH_VERSION zsh=$ZSH_VERSION"` and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

##### explaining

```bsh
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

- this means **if** there's a file with the name of **.bash_aliases** then **source** that file. The `.` in bash is the same as **source**, example:
  `. .bash_aliases` or `source .bash_aliases`,the same just a **shortcut.**
- `~/` is a shortcut for your home directory, meaning, `/home/agent/`.You're sourcing in the **root** directory. That's why you are logged as **root** in the terminal. When you source `~/.bash_aliases` nothing happens because you are sourcing a file that doesn't have your alias **up**.

```bsh
source /home/agent/.bash_aliases
```

##### solution

*don't do it as root*, do it as your user[agent]
a. remove the .bash_aliases from the root `/` directory

```bsh
sudo rm /.bash_aliases
```

b. open with **gedit** your file .bash_aliases at **HOME DIRECTORY** and notice the `.` in front of `.bash_aliases`

```bsh
gedit /home/agent/.bash_aliases` #and add your alias
alias up='sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade'
```

c. **source** file **.bashrc** and this will automatically **source** the `.bash_aliases`
(remember the `if [-f ~/.bash_aliases]; then` at the beginning?)

```bsh
source /home/agent/.bashrc
```

d. you can check your aliases with the **command** `alias -p`

Comment: Just FYI: in general, `.` is preferred over `source` since `.` is the standard, portable, POSIX name for the command and `source` is a bashism. Of course, this isn't a problem here since we're discussing bash-specific files, but just so you know, `source` is the alias, and `.` the main command.